# T-Mobile G1 won't appear in 'adb devices' list

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I'm trying to connect to connect to my T-Mobile G1 to test a simple android app I an creating.  I cannot get it to show up in the list of connected android devices. Here are the details:

- 32-bit Windows XP
- I have enabled USB Debugging on my device
- I am not prompted with the New Hardware Wizard when I plug my device in, it is merely seen as a new removable drive.  It does not appear under any other categories in Device Manager, nor is there a new "Unknown Device" entry anywhere to be found
- I have tried "Update Driver" and select the driver that Google provides for their official developer devices, but it says "this driver does not match your device" or something to that effect.  Probably because it is expected a device type other than "Disk Drive"
- I have tried uninstalling the device under "Disk Drives" and plugging it in again but it always gets reinstalled automatically as a "Disk Drive"
- I have tried uninstalling the device, manually installing the Google driver from the INF file and plugging in the device and it is still only recognized as a "Disk Drive"
- Most importantly, I get a blank device list when I run "adb devices" from the Android SDK tools directory before and after each step I tried

After hours of scouring the web I get the distinct impression that a new device category should be popping up in Device Manager if the driver is installed correctly, but I have not been able to get the device to come up as anything other than a new "Disk Drive"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must install compatible HTC Sync on the windows. HTC Sync can be downloaded in http://www.htc.com/

Comment: I scoured the HTC site and do not see a version of Sync available for the G1.

Comment: You can try the version for dream. The phone is similar to G1.

Comment: imcaptor - the Dream Sync Software worked.  Thanks, I've been beating my head against the wall on this one.  Google's documentation says the G1 should be supported out of the box with App Inventor but apparently that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the driver manually via Windows Device Manager.

If it's not showing up as the phone, you may need to plug it in and remove it a couple times to determine which device it is showing up as.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse.  Unfortunately I have tried that.  (see bullet points #4 and #5).  Always shows up as "Disk Drive" no matter how many times I reconnect it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to install the driver onto your phone with these instructions:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Note that the directory has changed to /extras/google/usb_driver.